# Nginx Cache doesn't refresh

Tags: caching, nginx, forever

I configured nginx to cache all files for 3min. This works only for files I upload to the webserver manually. All files generated by the CMS get cached forever (or a long time I didn't wait)...

The CMS delivers all pages as "index.html" with an own folder structure (www.x.de/category1/category2/articlename/index.html).

How can I debug this? Is there a way to check the lifetime of a specific file?
Can something in the .html files overwrite the proxy_cache_valid value?

Many thanks!

Config:

```
server {
listen 1.2.3.4:80 default_server;

server_name x.de;
server_name www.x.de;
server_name ipv4.x.de;


client_max_body_size 128m;
location / { # IPv6 isn't supported in proxy_pass yet.
proxy_pass http://apache.ip:7080;
proxy_cache my-cache;
proxy_cache_valid 200 3m;
proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
access_log off;

}

location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
alias /var/www/vhosts/x.de/httpdocs/cms/;
access_log /var/www/vhosts/x.de/statistics/logs/proxy_access_log;
add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;
internal;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `curl -I`, you can retrieve the headers which will tell you what the cache settings are.

E.g.

```
>>> curl -I http://www.google.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 09 Feb 2014 06:28:36 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Cache settings are done in the response headers, so it's not possible for html to modify those.